# Python lambda dp calculation

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I am trying to understand below code snippet, for each value of i, what are all the two arguments passed to `min()`? appreciate if you could explain how the `dp[i]` computation could be expanded?

```
class Solution(object):

    def coinChange(self, coins, amount):
        MAX = float('inf')
        dp = [0] + [MAX] * amount
        print(dp)

        for i in range(1, amount + 1):
            dp[i] = min([dp[i - c] if i - c >= 0 else MAX for c in coins]) + 1

        print(dp)
        return [dp[amount], -1][dp[amount] == MAX]
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things are happening here. 
The `min()` method is receiving a python list as an argument.

This python list is created through [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It helps to start from the back. The list comprehension is saying "For every value `c` in the iterable `coins`, append the value `dp[i - c]` to my list if the boolean `i - c >=0` is `True`. Otherwise, append the value `MAX`.

In other words, the line `[dp[i - c] if i - c >= 0 else MAX for c in coins]` is equivalent to

```
def makelist(dp,i,MAX,coins):
    ret = []
    for c in coins:
        if i - c >= 0:
            ret.append(dp[i-c])
        else:
            ret.append(MAX)
    return ret
```

The `min()` method will be performed on this list once it is complete, which simply find the smallest value in the list